# I Made a maze in AS3 and the maze wont go to my win screen when the player hits the exit

Tags: puzzle, maze, actionscript-3

I made A Maze and Action script 3.0 and everything works except when the player touches the exit box (a movie clip called exit) the maze wont go to my win screen.
 If someone could help me that'd be great because this is a final project for school

here's my code

```
  var rightArrow:Boolean = false;   
    var leftArrow:Boolean = false;
    var upArrow:Boolean = false;
    var downArrow:Boolean = false;
    var speed:int = 5;

    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, stage_onKeyDown);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, stage_onKeyUp);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, stage_onEnterFrame);

    function stage_onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) rightArrow = true;
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) leftArrow = true;
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) upArrow = true;
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) downArrow = true;
    }
    function stage_onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) rightArrow = false;
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) leftArrow = false;
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) upArrow = false;
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) downArrow = false;
    }
    function stage_onEnterFrame(event:Event):void {
        var rect:Rectangle = player.getBounds(this);
        var i:int = 0;
        var xBump:int = 0;
        var yBump:int = 0;
        if(rightArrow) {
            xBump = speed;
            for(i = 0; i < speed; i++) {
                if(maze.hitTestPoint(rect.right + i, player.y, true)) {
                    xBump = i - 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(leftArrow) {
            xBump = -speed;
            for(i = 0; i < speed; i++) {
                if(maze.hitTestPoint(rect.left - i, player.y, true)) {
                    xBump = -i + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(upArrow) {
            yBump = -speed;
            for(i = 0; i < speed; i++) {
                if(maze.hitTestPoint(player.x, rect.top - i, true)) {
                    yBump = -i + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(downArrow) {
            yBump = speed;
            for(i = 0; i < speed; i++) {
                if(maze.hitTestPoint(player.x, rect.bottom + i, true)) {
                    yBump = i - 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        player.x += xBump;
        player.y += yBump;
    }

if(player.hitTestObject(exit)) {
                gotoAndStop("win");
            }
stop();
```

Answer (score -1):

Your test:

```
if(player.hitTestObject(exit)) {
            gotoAndStop("win");
}
```

appears to be outside the function `stage_onEnterFrame` and is thus only executed once. Make sure the closing brace of the function:

```
    player.x += xBump;
    player.y += yBump;
}         // this one
```

Comes after the test, like so:

```
    }
    player.x += xBump;
    player.y += yBump;


    if(player.hitTestObject(exit)) {
            gotoAndStop("win");
    }
} // closing function here, NOT above
```

Comment: @Luke: glad I could help. On [so], you can show that an answer was helpful by either upvoting it (up arrow) or accepting it (green tick)